# loading data from external stage - check if file exists before loading

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ksh

I'm using snowsql in a ksh script which loading data from a named external stage to snowflake table.
I want to check if a file exists before loading: if no files there, I'd like to exit without doing the load.
I tried using

```
snowsql -c $CONNECT -w $WAREHOUSE -s $SCHEMA -d $DATABASE \
-o exit_on_error=true \
-q "ls ${external_stage};" \
```

but the result of ls is empty - not consider as error.

How do I approach it?

Comment: You need to script that in your ksh script rather than in the *snowsql* run. So the idea is that your ksh script needs to parse the output from *snowsql* and then based on that you can take an action.

Comment: @Sergiu Thanks! i ended up passed the result to a variable in ksh, as you said, it's working good!